# Omnet++: How to implement OSPF routing over a StandardHost based node?

Tags: omnet++

I have a network of nodes in random topology. Those nodes use UDP for communication and are submodules based on "StandardHost".

I want to have shortest route between 2 nodes for which I would like to use OSPF. Now in order to have such mechanism how do I add this property of OSPF to my node?

Answer (score 1):

In short, you'll need to include a module in you StandardHost that implements this routing mechanism. I assume you've already found the [INET Framework](https://inet.omnetpp.org/), which has an implementation of OSPF; their source code actually has a bunch of examples for OSPF (which you can find [here](https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/tree/master/examples/ospfv2)). This means you'll end up with a `.ned` file that references the OSPF module in some way -- unfortunately I don't have experience with the module itself, so I can't tell you how its internals work, but if you look at the simple example included in the source, you'll find that the `omnetpp.ini` contains a reference to a UDP Echo Application, and [this code](https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/blob/master/examples/ospfv2/simpletest/SimpleTest.ned#L82-L86) (as well as the rest of that file) shows how the routers and hosts are connected.

Comment: alright I am getting a little hang of it. Also I see that in the examples of inet i have seen that generally in the networks configurator is being deployed. Now if I use a IPv4 configurator and I dont edit any proprerty in it then does it differ to the scenario where I dont use any configurator?

Comment: @VijayRana I'm not sure how the configurators affect the simulation. The OMNeT++ tools I use are designed in such a way that I have a network specified, and the nodes are generated dynamically and attached to the network medium by the tool's logic, so I don't really know how it works for static network configurations.

Comment: that can be done by specifying xml file file for scenariomanager for dynamic behavious of adding nodes or routing etc.When I went through the INET framework example for OSPFv2 there are concepts of using areas and each area has a router or set of routers connected to the hosts in that area. My doubt is if I have say suppose 10 nodes connected in k-ary tree pattern and i would like to have routing among those nodes then How should I be adding OSPF routers in such network and where to do so?

Comment: @VijayRana it depends on what exactly you want to do. Either A) you want many hosts that communicate directly using OSPF, or B) you want to simulate OSPF itself, in which case you're not only interested in hosts, but also and primarily in routers. If you're working on evaluating something at the application layer, I suspect you're looking for A), and the code I linked should allow you to connect them directly. If you're looking for B), you'll need to think closely about what it is you're trying to determine exactly, and design your experiments accordingly.

Comment: Regarding B), for example, if you're studying how OSPF deals with lost routes, you'll need a sufficiently complex network that can actually have this problem and recover. Unfortunately it's difficult for me to provide helpful comments about B), because I'm not familiar with OSPF. In general, try to define as specifically as possible what the goal of your experiment is, and find the edge cases associated with that.

Comment: okay. As you have asked about my case then I just need to have OSPF routing among the nodes: I have considered nodes which are StandardHost based. If I extend the StandardHost so to add OSPF routing property on such node what exactly is to be done? Taking nodes by extending OSPFRouter or taking nodes as submodules of OSPFRouter would do the same or not?